# JSTL Concatenate String to be used in html

Tags: jstl

how would I concatenate a string so It can be rendered in HTML properly?

```
<c:set var="filter" value="${view}"/>
```

For example, I do something like this in JavaScript:

```
var view;
var sors;
var filterCriteria = view + "<br>";
if  (sors != null)  
{
   filterCriteria = filter + "SORs: " + sors + ", ";
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. What does `view` contains, and what do you want to output as HTML?

Comment: Im trying to concatenenate html to the string so when its redered it wont show the html text......my javascript example shows how I do it in javascript

Comment: Still not clear. Why don't you answer my questions? What does the `view` variable contain? What do you want to output as HTML?

Comment: view is a string!  I want view <br> whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then the answer is

```
${view} <br> whatever
```

or

```
<c:out value="${view}"> <br> whatever
```

The first one doesn't escape the HTML special chars in `view` (`<`, `>`, `&`, `'`, `"`), whereas the second one does (and transforms them to `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, etc.)

Comment: Then it means that the `view` attribute contains the string `OVERALL`. What's the problem? And why can't you use c:out?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output `<br>` as html tag you could use `c:out` as `<c:out escapeXml="false" value="${view} <br>"/>`